# Files in tmp directory still taking up space after deletion ios

Tags: ios, swift, memory, tmp

I am saving media data to the iPhones tmp directory and after it is no longer needed I delete all the files. However I have noticed in my phones settings menu, under storage that my applications memory is increasing every time I save a new file and then later delete it. I am pretty sure the files are being removed because if I try to delete the same file again it throws an exception that it doesn't exist. Here is my code for deleting everything in tmp:

```
let content = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
for path in content {
     let fullPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(path)
     try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fullPath.absoluteString)
}
```

The weird thing is that sometimes after not using the application and coming back the memory goes down, keyword being sometimes. Am I doing something wrong and/or is there anything else I can do to minimize the memory footprint of my application in regards to the tmp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out passing it a NSURL vs string was the solution, now the files are definitely being deleted:

```
for path in content2 {
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(path)
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath!)
}
```